# Excluding config class from being scanned for integration test in Spring Boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, junit, configuration, integration-testing

I have multiple test classes in Spring Boot. I want to create an integration test in my tests folder which also contains 4 unit tests. These 4 unit tests connect to an endpoint test config class that has beans the unit tests use.

I want this new integration test class to not hit my endpoint test config class but that it is currently doing that even though it is not auto wired and it is causing a bean instantiation error.

```
Description:

The bean 'getVersionEndPoint', defined in class path resource [com/nulogix/billing/configuration/EndPointTestConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in file [/Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator/target/classes/com/nulogix/billing/ws/endpoint/GetVersionEndPoint.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I was thinking to find a way for SpringBootTest to ignore it. I tried doing this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.nulogix.billing.App;
import com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties=
{"spring.autoconfigure.exclude=comma.seperated.ClassNames,com.nulogix.billing.configuration.EndPointTestConfiguration"})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,classes = {App.class,MockServerApp.class
})
public class BillingMediatorIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void testOne(){


        }
    }
```

This did not work though because my endpointconfig class is not an AutoConfig.

How do I set it up to ignore the class? Can I do it in the pom.xml using a Maven plugin? I eventually want it so when I run mvn verify it just runs the integration tests but first I want it to ignore the my config class.

I have tried creating a filter but it also seemed to not work

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,classes = {MockServerApp.class,App.class
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nulogix.billing",
                excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = EndPointTestConfiguration.class))
public class BillingMediatorIT {


        @Test
        public void testOne(){


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use profiles, which provide a flexible way to exclude classes from your Spring context.

Annotate your test config class (EndPointTestConfiguration) with @Profile("test"). It will not be instanciated by Spring unless you activate the "test" profile.

You can activate the profile in a test by using the @ActiveProfiles annotation.

You can read more here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: This worked. Allowing bean definition overriding to be set to true also worked but I feel like this is not recommended and could cause problems down the road.